# How can I write a python script to read a file and return the version

Tags: python, linux

I need to write a python script to read the README.txt file on /opt/atlassian/jira and return the version displayed below as 6.3.8

Here are the contents on the README.txt file

---

### JIRA 6.3.8-#6338 README

Thank you for downloading JIRA 6.3.8. This distribution comes with a
built-in Tomcat 7.0.55 application server, so it runs (almost)
out of the box.

### BRIEF INSTALL GUIDE

1. Install Oracle's (formerly Sun's) Java Development Kit (JDK) or
   Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 or above:
   ........

and so on

Comment: Also, that output looks like a rendered version of the txt file. If there's headers and bold text and ordered lists I'm betting the actual txt file itself contains something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at doing something like this. Also as stated earlier if there is rendered text you will need to either change the if conditional to reflect that or you will need to add a nested if statement to narrow it down. You may not need to typecast. Hope this sends you in the right direction.

```
readme_file = open("/pathto/somefile.txt")

for line in readme_file.xreadlines():
    if line.startswith("JIRA"):
        version_num = str(line).split()[1].split("-")[0]
        break
    else:
        continue
readme_file.close()
```

Here is a good resource for opening files in python:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm

Comment: Thank you very much. Also what is the command to check if the file exists?

Comment: import os

os.path.exists("/some/path/text.txt")

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html

Feel free to mark this as correct if it helped you.

Comment: def jira_check(module):
    dirs = ["/opt/atlassian/jira"]
    for dir_name in dirs:
        if os.path.exist(dir_name):
            readme_file = open("%s/README.txt")
            for line in readme_file.xreadlines():
                if line.startswith("JIRA"):
                    version = str(line).split()[1].split("-")[0]
                    return {'version': version}
                    break
                else:
                    continue
            readme_file.close()

Comment: 172.30.0.63 | FAILED >> {
    "failed": true,
    "msg": "SUDO-SUCCESS-xrgbdfmrpbznttqsiojitvijtyonxsyi\nTraceback (most recen in main\n  File \"<stdin>\", line 83, in jira_check\nAttributeError: 'module' o
    "parsed": false
}

Comment: I got this figured out. Thanks a lot Minelr G.